# React Axios - download excel file from Django backend

Tags: reactjs, django, excel, download, axios

I am trying to download excel file which is generated by Django backend:

```
class GenerateExcel(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        filename = 'File.xlsx'
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.title = "Workbook"
        response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
        return response
```

If I send request with a postman I get success response and I can download the file via option Save Response -> Save to a file and it works fine.

If I try to download it in my frontend with axios I am able to download the excel file but it has different size then the file from a postman and it is not possible to open the excel file. I receive the file is corrupted error.
I am using redux so this code is in actions file:

```
export const getYhrtaskgrpExcel = (fromDate, toDate) => async dispatch => {
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1/excel-report/`;

    try {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_EXCEL_REQUEST
        });

        const res = await axios.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
        dispatch({
            type: GET_EXCEL_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });
        console.log('this is data: ', res.data);
        var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
        var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type:'application/ms-excel'});
        FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "excel.xlsx");
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_EXCEL_FAIL,
            payload: error.data
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Comment: I have not yet.

Comment: Try to use `axios.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})`. It's work for me.

Comment: @SonTran Your solution works for me too. Thanks mate!